# android - Google maps flickering behind the progress view when clicking on back button

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, samsung-galaxy

I have a google map application (using google-maps:16). ProgressView is the custom class layout which I used to display ProgressBar with text inside it. The issue is that when I go to map fragment, if gps is on then, it will try to fetch user current location. While fetching current location, to show progress I am displaying ProgressView with some text above MapView. There is a back button in the toolbar. Whenever I click that back button in toolbar, sometimes the part of google map behind the ProgressView is flickering. This is happening only sometimes. And it is only coming when I am running my app on Samsung Galaxy S8 (API 26).

The flickering doesn't appear when I remove the ProgressView from the layout but the progress view is need to show. Below it the layout of that fragment:

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            map:cameraTargetLat="33.753746"
            map:cameraTargetLng="-84.386330"
            map:cameraZoom="14" />

        <ProgressView
            android:id="@+id/findProgressView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone" />
   </FrameLayout>
```

The expected result is that google map should not flicker with ProgressView.

Answer (score 4):

Had a similar problem, where the `MapView` was flickering on specifically pressing the back button of the `Toolbar`.

I did try testing [Andrey Smolyak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57322274/13319203)'s answer and it actually seemed to work.

Although, the final way I did it was to change the `LayerType` of the `MapView` to "hardware accelerated" in XML.

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layerType="hardware"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The same can be achieved in Java/Kotlin code:

```
mapView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced same problem.
I suppose that ripple animation on toolbar button is somehow affecting google maps.

You can disable ripple animation for back button on toolbar. I know it's dirty hack, but it fixes that problem in my case.